# setText method not working properly?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am trying to execute the settext method on my textview but it doesn't seem to work. I learned that "%s" in the first argument of the string.format method should return the given string of the second argument but it somehow it doesn't work.

```
SPCalories = Double.longBitsToDouble(sharedPreferences.getLong("Calories", Double.doubleToLongBits(0)));
d_c = SPCalories;
dc_text = Double.toString(d_c);
Calories_text.setText(R.string.Calories + String.format("%s", dc_text));
```

R.string.Calories:

```
<string name="Calories">Calories: </string>
```

Am I doing something wrong with SharedPreferences maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do:

```
<string name="Calories">Calories: %s</string>
```

And:

```
Calories_text.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.Calories), dc_text));
```

Answer (score 0):

You omitted `getString` method:

```
Calories_text.setText(getString(R.string.Calories) + String.format("%s", dc_text));
```

If you wold like to learn more about formatting strings check:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling.